# Lagrangian Optimization Linear in Constants Comparison?

Tags: optimization, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let there be a function f, continuous, differenciable, and positive monotonic in variables x and y. 
For example, let f be

$f(x,y) = (a*x^2 + b*y^2)/2$

, where a and b are constants

, and let us try to max this function with a constraint, take
$max(x,y) f, s.t. x+y=1$

Using lagrangian, we need

$∂f / ∂x = ∂f / ∂y$

, which implies $ax=by$

, or $a/b=y/x$

this implies the larger a to b ratio, the smaller the x to y ratio, and is very counterintuitive to me. Should the larger a is the more valuable x is and more goes to x?

Here my solution is $x = b/(a+b)$

The more valuable y is the more should be spend on x?
This is neither the min solution

How did I use lagrangian wrong? Or are the preconditions not met?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For positives $a$ and $b$ by C-S
$$\frac{ax^2+by^2}{2}=\frac{\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}\right)(ax^2+by^2)}{2\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}\right)}\geq\frac{(x+y)^2}{2\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}\right)}=\frac{ab}{2(a+b)}.$$
The equality occurs for
$$\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}\right)||\left(\sqrt ax,\sqrt by\right)$$ or $$ax=by,$$  which says that we got a minimal value.

The maximum value does not exist.

For $a<0$ and $b<0$ by the similar way we can get a maximal value: $\frac{ab}{2(a+b)}.$

Comment: @Thomas Zhang See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you give a reference educational material to teach me your C-S, I am actually an economist and only tought the most naive way of lagraugian. I can see why there is no maximum, there has to be extra constraints for x and y to be positive in my case and the the tangent solution would be in the negative region. I recall KKT for that. Can I learn your method of solving these? I dont quite understand thr steps. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the link!

Comment: The C-S is glorious! Thanks! Now I understand your proof! Thanks very much!

Comment: You are welcome Thomas!